# I would expect the output to be like [[0,0,0,0,],[0,1,0,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,3,0,0]]

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-lists, assign

```
time_count = [[0, 0, 0, 0]] * 4
j = 0
for i in range(len(time_count)):
    time_count[i][1] = j
    j += 1
print(time_count)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

I would expect the output to be like:

```
[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,3,0,0]]
```

can someone explain why every `index[1]` is `3` ?

Comment: The `*` operator creates new references to the (same) list. If you change one you are changing all.

Comment: Bravo!! I see but How can I create a long list without writing every element down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, The entities of a list are pointers to a particular memory location.  When one assigns list(a) to list(b) It implies that list(b) points to the same memory location as the list(a).

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = a
 a = [3, 4, 5]
 print(a, b)

 [3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3]
```

In the above-asked question if the inside of the nested list is multiplied by 4 times then all the sublists point to the same memory location. so, If one of the sublists is changed then the change is propagated to all of the sublists, Which basically creates unexpected results upon code execution. For anyone interested to know more,
the video sums up all the basic features of lists that are not obvious. It also explains the above question in further detail.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Answer (score 4):

Easy fix:

```
time_count = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for _ in range(4)]
```

As Klaus D. has alluded, using the `*` operator on nested lists is usually a bad idea, as it duplicates the contents by copying the references. You won't notice this when multiplying sequences of immutable types, e.g. a list of integers, but when the elements are mutable, you get duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

It's not good to write a list as [[0, 0, 0, 0]]*4. Lists are mutable. Each time you change any of the list elements all the copies of it will change. one good way to write is as below because that way you are not copying list elements.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
time_count = [[0, 0, 0, 0]] * 4
print([[v if x!=1 else i for x,v in enumerate(a)] for i,a in enumerate(time_count)])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

### UPDATE:

**Explanation:**

1. Use `enumerate` to iterate trough both the indexes and values of the list `time_count`.
2. Use `enumerate` again to iterate trough both the indexes and values of the list `a`. *which is the iterator for `time_count`*.
3. Go trough the indexes of `a` and say `i` (the index iterator for `time_count`) if `x` (the index iterator for `a`) is 1, otherwise say `v` (the iterator for `a`)

*Note: This is all in a list comprehension*

Answer (score 1):

The * operator just creates a new reference to the original list (here `[0, 0, 0, 0]`).

If you change the original list as `time_count[i][1] = j`, all the references reflect the same changes.

If you want to create a new list, you can use the extend method with a loop on it :

```
time_count = []
time_count.extend([0,0,0,0] for _ in range(4))
```

Now, all the element list in time_count store separate memory and can have different values.